# How to communicate between Backend (microservices) in AWS EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I have 2 node js backend applications, they depend on each other, but I'm confused about how these 2 backends communicate in Kubernetes AWS EKS

Answer (score 1):

In a default k8s setting, creating a service and registering pods into it will create an internal dns address each pod can use to reach another one.

So, if your services are named `service-a` and `service-b`, `service-a` can reach `service-b` by sending requests to the `service-a` host.
The FQDN for each service is `service-<x>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

More information can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)